# How to detect Tab press in Inno Setup Form

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to detect when user press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in setup (e.g. when focus is being changed from one control to another).

Here is my code, but the **MsgBox is never executed**.

What am I doing wrong?

```pascal
[Code]

procedure OnKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure OnKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
   MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure OnKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
   MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
   MainForm.OnKeyDown := @OnKeyDown;
   MainForm.OnKeyPress := @OnKeyPress;
   MainForm.OnKeyUp := @OnKeyUp;
end;
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to manipulate with the focus on controls - set it/kill it.

Comment: Unless you understand, how the dialog manager works, you are going to break it.

Comment: @IInspectable is right. There are may other way to change the focus, than by the `Tab` key. You might want to give us a broader picture of what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `WizardForm` instead of `MainForm` and also set the `KeyPreView` to true:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
   WizardForm.OnKeyDown := @OnKeyDown;
   WizardForm.OnKeyPress := @OnKeyPress;
   WizardForm.OnKeyUp := @OnKeyUp;
   WizardForm.KeyPreview:=true;
end;
```

But I'm not sure if it catches Virtual Keys.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I was missing the KeyPreview:=true; and WizardForm instead of MainForm;